# Is this possible to merge the Google Drive and one Drive

Tags: onedrive, google

I have a question. Is this possible to combine or merge the Google and one Drive accounts. Please Let me know the details.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge the Google and one Drive accounts"?

Comment: i want to sync the file between both drives.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about Windows Phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, Its possible to combine both online Drive's.

use this site:
https://www.multcloud.com
for this site we can able to merge and transfer the data without download&upload

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both Google Drive and OneDrive are storage solutions of different companies - Google and Microsoft. You can manually copy the files from one to another and stop using the former. If you have programming experience, you may even write your own Windows app.